# Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: relation "databasechangelog" does not exist

Tags: liquibase

When running a liquibase (version 3.5.3) deployment against a new postgres database, we are getting the error below.  The table, databasechangelog, did not get created by liquibase, but the table, databasechangeloglock, did get created.

```
INFO 2/7/17 1:27 PM: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 2/7/17 1:27 PM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Unexpected error running Liquibase: ERROR: relation "audit.databasechangelog" does not exist
  Position: 20

 SEVERE 2/7/17 1:27 PM: liquibase: ERROR: relation "audit.databasechangelog" does
    not exist
      Position: 20
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL SELECT MD5SUM FROM au
dit.databasechangelog WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1: ERROR: relation "audit.d
atabasechangelog" does not exist
  Position: 20
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:68)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query(JdbcExecutor.java:126)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.query(JdbcExecutor.java:134)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForList(JdbcExecutor.java:20
0)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForList(JdbcExecutor.java:19
4)
        at liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService.init(StandardChan
geLogHistoryService.java:212)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.checkLiquibaseTables(Liquibase.java:1124)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:205)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1130)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:188)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:103)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "audit.databasecha
ngelog" does not exist
  Position: 20
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryEx
ecutorImpl.java:2455)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutor
Impl.java:2155)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.ja
va:288)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)

        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:303
)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:289
)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:266
)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:233)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$QueryStatementCallback.doInStatem
ent(JdbcExecutor.java:345)
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
        ... 11 more
```

There are two schemas, ods and audit.  And the search_path is ods, audit, public.  We specify the target schema in the connection string (currentSchema=audit).  Additionally, we ran successfully against the ods schema.
As a workaround, we can manually create the log table.  However, I am wondering if this is a bug with liquibase or if we are doing something wrong?  My thought is that liquibase is somehow seeing the ods.databasechangelog and skips creating it.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

m

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try to use following liquibase parameter:
`--defaultSchemaName=<schema>`

Comment: "Maybe" and "try" are not words that should be in an answer on SO. Concentrate on questions that you can write complete solutions to that you know solve the asker's problem. Once you have 50 rep you can use comments to ask for clarification or make suggestions.